# About two way fixed effect

Tags: econometrics, propensity-scores

> Question: Suppose there is a job training program rolled out in Georgia from 2011 to 2015 . The aim of the job training program is to provide work experience for a period of 12 to 18 months to individuals who had faced economic and social problems prior to enrollment in the program. There are 60 out of 159 counties in Georgia implemented this program over the five years, and each year there are 5 counties starting this program. The program will continue as long as the county started the program. Suppose you have data on county-level employments from 2010 to 2020, and you run a two-way fixed effects event-study model to estimate the average treatment effect of the program on the treated (i.e., ATT). Will this give you an unbiased estimate of the ATT? If your answer is no, how would you estimate the ATT?

Two way Fixed effect works when effects are homogenous across units and across time periods, and the effect is good for newly treated units v.s control and bad for newly treated v.s already treated.

Since the data only contains employments, there can be bias in effect, i.e. different age groups. Also we do not know whether employed people are already treated or not. So two way fixed effect does not work, and we should do propensity score matching first and evaluate using this formula:

$$
A T E=E\left[\frac{\left(T_i-\mu_i\right) y_i}{\mu_i\left(1-\mu_i\right)}\right], \quad A T T=E\left[\frac{\left(T_i-\mu_i\right) y_i}{P\left(T_i=1\right)\left(1-\mu_i\right)}\right]
$$
where $\mu_i \equiv \mu\left(x_i\right) \equiv P\left(T_i=1 \mid x_i\right)=E\left(T_i \mid x_i\right)$ is the propensity score.

Is my reasoning correct? Please let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks.